# opensearch - how to update index transform

Tags: opensearch

1. we have an index transform job which needs to be updated between product versions.
2. we use the rest command below to create the transform job:

```
PUT _plugins/_transform/transform_test
{
  "transform": {
    "enabled": true,
    "schedule": {
      "interval": {
        "period": 1,
        "unit": "Minutes",
        "start_time": 1602100553
      }
    },
    "description": "create index device_usage_summary",
    "source_index": "device_usage_raw-*",
    "target_index": "transform_test",
    "data_selection_query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "range": {
              "message_header.occurred_message_display_time_utc_rfc3339": {
                "gte": "now-90d/d"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "page_size": 1,
    "groups": [
      {
        "terms": {
          "source_field": "device_information.removable_instance_path",
          "target_field": "usage_data.removable_instance_path"
        }
      },
      {
        "terms": {
          "source_field": "message_header.global_tenant_id",
          "target_field": "usage_data.global_tenant_id"
        }
      }
    ],
    "aggregations": {
      "usage_data.data_read_kb": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "usage_data.data_read_kb"
        }
      },
      "usage_data.data_write_kb": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "usage_data.data_write_kb"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. to update the transform job, we modify some of the fields and then run the SAME command again (as documented in opensearch documentation (https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/im-plugin/index-transforms/transforms-apis/#update-a-transform-job  updating )
   however we get error :

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason" : "[transform_test]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [1])",
        "index" : ".opendistro-ism-config",
        "shard" : "4",
        "index_uuid" : "XYKR62x6QBmt8C9qcHONnQ"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "version_conflict_engine_exception",
    "reason" : "[transform_test]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [1])",
    "index" : ".opendistro-ism-config",
    "shard" : "4",
    "index_uuid" : "XYKR62x6QBmt8C9qcHONnQ"
  },
  "status" : 409
}
```

so our question is: how do we update a transform job after it exists?